# Sorting PHP based on key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array with the following keys:

```
comm_id, 
user_name, 
comm_type, 
comm_message, 
created_at
```

Some example data for the array is below:

1. Gandalf Greybeard, E-Mail, Example E-Mail Message, 2014-01-03 23:00:00
2. Joffrey Baratheon, Text, Nasty piece of work, 2014-01-03 23:20:00
3. Gandalf Greybeard, Text, Test, 2014-01-03 23:10:00
4. Tyrion Lannister, Log, This email is from Tyrion Lannister, 2014-01-03 23:30:00
5. Gandalf Greybeard, E-Mail, Another Test, 2014-01-03 23:40:00

How would I then create an array of only the latest communication of user_name (regardless of the comm_type) for each user from the array, so only id's 5, 4 and 2?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your array, making a new array with a key of the user_name. Only insert into the array if the key doesn't exist or has a higher created_at...

like this:

```
$final_array = array()
foreach ($comm_log as $comm) {
  if (!key_exists($comm['comm_id'], $final_array) 
      || $final_array[$comm['comm_id']] < $comm['created_at']) 
    {
       $final_array[$comm['comm_id']] = $comm
    }
}
```

Your $final_array will have only the most recent communications.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the communications, keeping the maximum in each case.

```
$result = array();
foreach($communications as $communication) {
    $user = $communication['user_name'];
    if (isset($result[$user])){
        $result[$user] = max($result[$user], $communication['created_at']);
    } else {
        $result[$user] = $communication['created_at'];
    }
}
```

You may need to convert the dates to actual date objects, so the comparison works.